# is KEY_ID automatically generated for sqlite database tables in Android? and is it called "KEY_ID"?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have an sqlite database with one table in an android app. When it was created with the statement shown below there are two collumns, KEY_CHECKBOX_STATUS and KEY_CHECKBOX_LABEL.  "ID" is the primary key that was created.

If I do not explicitly create a primary key at creation time like in the following statement, does it automatically get created?  and is the name, "KEY_ID"?

```
  //create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
    private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
     "CREATE_TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " (" + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +  
     KEY_CHECKBOX_STATUS + " BIT, " + KEY_CHECKBOX_LABEL + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqlite will create a `"rowid"` and it is unique. You can access this using `"rowid" or "oid" or "_rowid_"`. For example SELECT rowid as id ...
You can read more here http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html. Note that rowid is case insensitive.

Comment: You can also access it as 'ID' since your create includes "ID integer primary key", so 'ID' becomes another synonym for rowid.

Comment: Yes, if he created, in his question he asked if he did not created the primary key ID and if he did not then he cannot access rowid using ID.

Comment: Oh, whoops - I stand corrected.  I will note though that I read in other SO posts that it is better to declare the primary key ID (even if you don't need it), and just let Sqlite implement it as an alias of rowid.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But his question is specific that if he did not created KEY_ID.